# How to write PHP script for cronjob that uses cat /dev/null > to reset log files

Tags: php, linux, cron, plesk

I could use some assistance in making a PHP script that I could add to a cronjob that would include multiple, (10 to 15), commands such as:

```
line1: cat /dev/null > /var/www/vhosts/website.com
/logs/access_log.webstat  
line2: cat /dev/null > /var/www/vhosts/website.com/logs/big_access_log
line3: cat /dev/null > /var/log/plesk-roundcube/largefile.log
```

and so on. The commands work great from a command line, but doing this daily is time consuming and the files grow way too large even though they are being rotated. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What is the question specifically? Just how to do this in php? If so, probably just look into the php `exec` function.

Comment: why php? something that simple is trivially done in bash.

Comment: If you have direct access to cron, you should also be able to create your scripts in bash.

Answer (score 0):

Could you possibly use the [`shell_exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) command to complete these actions:

Example:

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('cat /dev/null > /var/www/vhosts/website.com /logs/access_log.webstat');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

Then just create a cron job to run them at interval times.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve the same result using native PHP code:

```
// The list of files to truncate
$listFiles = array(
    '/var/www/vhosts/website.com/logs/access_log.webstat',
    '/var/www/vhosts/website.com/logs/big_access_log',
    '/var/log/plesk-roundcube/largefile.log',
);

// Process all the files in the list
foreach ($listFiles as $filename) {
    // Open the file for writing ('w')
    // Truncate it to zero length if it exists, create it if it doesn't exist
    $fh = fopen($filename, 'w');
    // Close the file; this commits the new file size to the disk
    fclose($fh);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your assistance, the ending outcome is a awesome!
41 log files will no longer grow to gargantuan sizes. The implementation was as follows:

PHP script written as such:

```
    <?php
    $output = shell_exec('cat /dev/null > /var/www/vhosts/website.com/logs/access_log.webstat');
    $output = shell_exec('cat /dev/null > /var/www/vhosts/website.com/logs/big_access_log');
    $output = shell_exec('cat /dev/null > /var/log/plesk-roundcube/largefile.log');
    ?>
```

Then uploaded and set as a cron from the Plesk 12.5 panel. Tested and
functioning beautifully!

Answer (score 0):

It's quite strange, by default this files should be rotated by psa-logrotate.
Maybe something happens with logrotate package or crontask.

Here is a default settings for rotating of domain's logs:
[image: Plesk log rotate logrotate access.log error.log]